# Error while save the data from pyspark to HBase

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I am trying to write Spark Dataframe to HBase using PySpark. I uploaded spark HBase dependencies. By using Jupyter notebook I am running the code.
Also, I have created a table in HBase in the default namespace.

I started pyspark by running the below command.
My spark version: spark 3.x
and HBase version: hbase-2.2.6

```
pyspark --packages com.hortonworks:shc:1.0.0-1.6-s_2.10 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ --files /home/vijee/hbase-2.2.6-bin/conf/hbase-site.xml
```

The dependencies are successfully added

```
df = sc.parallelize([('a', 'def'), ('b', 'abc')]).toDF(schema=['col0', 'col1'])

catalog = ''.join("""{
     "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"smTable"},
     "rowkey":"c1",
     "columns":{
    "col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"c1", "type":"string"},
    "col1":{"cf":"t1", "col":"c2", "type":"string"}
   }
      }""".split())
      
df.write.options(catalog=catalog).format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase').save()
```

When I run the above statement, I am getting the below error. Since I am new to spark I was not able to understand the error.

At first, I tried with my CSV file and faced the same ": java.lang.AbstractMethodError". Now I am using the sample data still getting the same error.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-cfcf107b1f03> in <module>
----> 1 df.write.options(catalog=catalog,newtable=5).format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase').save()

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    823             self.format(format)
    824         if path is None:
--> 825             self._jwrite.save()
    826         else:
    827             self._jwrite.save(path)

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    126     def deco(*a, **kw):
    127         try:
--> 128             return f(*a, **kw)
    129         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    130             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o114.save.
: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/BaseRelation;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
```

Comment: try `.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")`?

Comment: @mck It didn't help. Again error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.

Comment: Try using Spark 3 with Hadoop 3.2 instead of 2.7. It seems as per the [docs](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop) there might be incompatibility issues